# Regex to match a URL with no file extension

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out a regex that will match a URL without a file extension.

Match:

- `https://www.stackoverflow.com/content/folder`
- `/other/content/folder`

Not Match:

- `https://www.stackoverflow.com/content/folder/file.js`
- `/other/content/folder/anotherFile.css`

I think the criteria i need is...

1. any string up to the last '`.`'
2. don't match if after the last '`.`' is a file extension

I appreciate the regex wont know if it is a file extension or not, so I'm happy to list the extensions in the regex like `.css|.js|.svg` etc, or whatever it might be.

I had this ( `^[^.]*$` ) matching the third example above, but as soon as more dots were present, it failed. I've been trying to find the last occurrence of a dot and check what is after it, but I can't figure it out.

Can anyone help please?

The regex is to be used with javascript.

Comment: A folder can contain a period (`.`) too.

Comment: When reading through a list of URLs I'm trying to pick out the URLs that are not files with file extensions

Comment: @DeanTaylor Yeah I appreciate that, thats why I thought the answer might involve listing the file extensions in the regex

Comment: You could easily have `example.com/people/mr.smith/photo-galleries/gallery1.jpg/example1` actually where `example1` is actually a filename - online - there is nothing to say an image has to have an file extension. The file type is included in the header response information

Comment: @DeanTaylor Well if presented with that specific link, I guess I wouldn't want the regex to match, but for my case I don't think it needs to be so robust. If I could filter based on what is after the last dot, that would be sufficient for my use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would match for any string that doesn't include a period "`.`" after the last "`/`" (or beginning of line of it's just a path name).

#### Regex

```
(?:/|^)[^./]+$
```

#### Example Use

```
if (/(?:\/|^)[^.\/]+$/.test(str)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

#### Human readable

```
(?:/|^)[^./]+$
```

Options: Case sensitive; Dot doesn’t match line breaks; ^$ don’t match at line breaks

- Match the regular expression below `(?:/|^)`

  - Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) `/`

    - Match the character “/” literally `/`
  - Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) `^`

    - Assert position at the beginning of the string `^`
- Match any single character NOT present in the list “./” `[^./]+`

  - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
- Assert position at the very end of the string `$`